# wordpress user profile url problem after import

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks, slug

I am using a wordpress theme and in this theme there are an import user option. Also I changed user's slug with a plugin that named [Edit Author Slug.](https://wordpress.org/plugins/edit-author-slug/)

After I import users by using theme's import user option, I am trying to access user's profile page with that 
[image: Trying to access Users profile page screen]
I am taking 404 error. And users slug url like this:

```
https://example.com/user_nicename/
```

But if I update user's profile from user's edit page user and I try to access user profile page I can access and user's slug converted to like this:

```
https://example.com/category/user_nicename/
```

And I can access now.

That's what I want:
After importing users, let me get the user urls automatically as in case 2 and get access user's profile without 404 error.

I searched a lot of but I didn't found any data for user's profile url in database. Maybe you can help me for finding where is the user slug urls storing.

Are there any solution or plugin for this. (This plugin should automatically update all users :) )

Note: I am using nginx server.